# Remove noise from the image and highlight the curves of the retina

Tags: c++, opencv, noise, retina

I have tried to extract only the blood vessels from the image of the retina, the last result I have had is the following, but there is still noise in the image, I do not know if anyone knows of any method to clean the image, I am interested in keeping the blood vessels of the retina and not lose information.

I would also like to highlight the blood vessels so that the veins that were cut due to the process are joined[image: retina]

Comment: Post your code and the original image.